# Binomial thinning of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to show that a random variable follows a specific law, how could I do that?

Let $\{A_{i,j}\}$ be an infinite iid array of Bernouilli($\psi$) variables and $\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_n$ be iid geometric($p$) random variables. Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be iid random variables defined by:
$$X_j=\sum_{i=1}^{\eta_j}A_{i,j}, \quad j=1,\ldots, n.$$
How could I show that
$$X\sim \mbox{geometric}\left(\frac{p}{\psi(1-p)+p}\right).$$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use moment generating function/characteristic function

MGF of bernoulli$(\psi)$ and geometric$(p)$ are $f(t)=1-\psi+\psi e^t$ and $g(t)=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t}$

$Ee^{tX_i} = E[E[e^{tX_i}|\eta_i]] = E(f(t)^{\eta_j})=E(1-\psi+\psi e^t)^{\eta_j}=g(\log(1-\psi+\psi e^t)) = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)(1-\phi+\phi e^t)}$

your job: rearrange the last expression to see that this is the MGF of geometric $(\frac{p}{\psi(1-p)+p})$

(I checked that this is correct but it is a lot of latex for a few lines of algebra)