# Probability - determining when a discrete random variable has geometric distribution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> We roll a fair $6$ sided die until we get $5$ or $6$. Let $X_A$ be the number of throws when rolled number $x\in A\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For which $A$, $X_A$ has geometric distribution $Geom(p)$, where $0<p\leq 1$?

It's pretty obvious, that for $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, we get a geometric distribution with $p=\frac{2}{3}$, but I fail to see how to check all other subsets... Is there a simple argument? I tried to count it, by conditioning on number of elements from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{5,6\}$but I haven't arrived to any useful conclusion.

Comment: $X_A$ is always geometric as long as you consider both versions of geometric - with support starting at $0$ and at $1$. See [Binomial Thinning of the Geometric](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647358/binomial-thinning-of-geometric-distribution)

Comment: Shouldn't be $5$ or $6$ always in $A$?